# Как убить все процессы, исключая некоторые Python

Tags: python, linux

У меня запущено несколько процессов:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
11491 pts/12   00:00:00 bash
12005 pts/12   00:00:00 Xfce4
13168 pts/12   00:00:01 vncserver
13179 pts/12   00:02:21 nano
[И еще несколько процессов]
```

Мне нужно остановить все процессы, кроме vncserver и bash, а так же кроме процесса самого python скрипта.
Как такое реализовать на linux?

Comment: при таком количестве легче это сделать ручками. killall поможет это сделать по имени.

Comment: А мне нужно автоматически, скриптом.

Comment: `$ pkill -t pts/12`. можно добавить и посылаемый сигнал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в стандартной поставке бывают команды pgrep и pkill (если нет, устанавливайте пакет procps)

теперь настраиваемся. Используем pgrep, что бы отфильтровать нужные процессы

```
pgrep -l vncserver\|bash
```

`-l` дает возможность увидеть не только pid, но и имена. Теперь, аккуартненько формируем список процессов на выживание. потом добавим `-v`, которая инвертирует условие. Хотя иногда лучше наоборот - сформировать список того, что нужно удалить.

ещё есть ключик `-u "$(whoami)"` который заставляет pgrep работать как ps без параметром. к сожалению, с `-v` оно работает не совсем так, как ожидается (показывает как раз все процессы, которые не пользователя...).

когда список будет готов, то вместо pgrep используем pkill, который и сделает черное дело.

но можно пойти дальше. у меня родился вот такой скрипт

```
ps | grep -v 'vnc\|bash' | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs kill -9
```

только вначале лучше его написать вот так

```
ps | grep -v 'vnc\|bash'
```

что бы посмотреть, что же по факту будет убиваться.

Потом вот так

```
ps | grep -v 'vnc\|bash' | cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

что бы убедится, что там правильные pid

А только потом уже добавить все остальное - kill c нужными параметрами.